How to see fraction line clearly in Windows Mathematica 14.0.0?
I just downloaded Mathematica 14.0.0 trial version on Windows 11. But the "horizontal fraction line" is hardly visible in the output on my screen. An example is shown below.

I couldn't find anything under Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance that seems related to this. I tried different Windows display settings, but to no avail either.
Any help on this please?

Sorry, I don't have an answer, but you might also look at a fraction line with and without a leading minus sign which has always been "less vivible" for me

Thanks, @Bill. I just tried "-1/2". It shows minus sign very clearly, but the fraction line is still nearly invisible.

As a temporary fix, I changed "Global Magnification" to 200% under Edit -> Preferences -> Interface. It's a lot larger, but at least the fraction line is visible.
